# Fast Text Search

Tags: java, string, algorithm, optimization

I wrote this code to search for a small text within a larger text. So far it is very slow. How do I optimize it? Please help me to optimize this code.

```
public class St {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    BufferedReader b1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String s=b1.readLine();
    String t=b1.readLine();
    String news = null;
    //double u=t.hashCode();
    //double q=s.hashCode();
    //double x;
    //.out.print(u+"\n"+q);
    int x=t.length();
    int y=s.length();
    for(int i=0;i<y-x-1;i++){



            //news=s.substring(i, i+t.length());
             //x=news.hashCode();


            //System.out.println(news);
        if(t.equals(s.substring(i, i+x))){
           System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there are smarter algorithms, you can achieve some non-trivial improvement without them. Just use what you've got in Java:

```
for (int i=hay.indexOf(needle); i!=-1; i=hay.indexOf(needle, i+1) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Your algorithm is damn slow as you `n` times copy `m` characters just to compare them. This one avoid copying altogether. While the complexity is still `O(m*n)` for practical strings it performs much better as usually just a couple of characters need to be compared.

Comment: O(m*n) is too large time complexity. I need more accurate way to do this.

Comment: @YasasPasindu You can use rolling hashcode, but this is one of the algorithms mentioned by Anirudh Ramanathan.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose one of the well-known algorithms, and their implementations in order to do searches of this nature.

Your options include [Knuth Morris Pratt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm), [Boyer Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) and [Rabin Karp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) algorithms. Each of them has their own complexity guarantees and one may be better than the other based on your input data.

Judging in terms of ease of implementation, Rabin Karp with a decent rolling hash function should give you acceptable performance. There is a reliable implementation provided [here](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/53substring/RabinKarp.java.html).

Another very good option that may be worth exploring is regular expressions. It is likely that the regex engine has a quick algorithm implemented to do substring matches of this nature.